# Insert the form values from an array into a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I have created a form that allows a user to upload multiple files to a directory. Now I am trying to grab the names of the files from the form input fields and store them into a database.

I am trying to get the array values of the input fields ie; the ['file']['name'] and the ['file']['tmp_name'] and insert them into a database. With the below code I have only managed to get the word "array" to be inserted into the database and not the actual names of the files themselves.

I think I need to loop through the array using a foreach loop but I am uncertain as to how to go about writing it and where to insert it into my code. Below is the code so far:

```
#connect to the database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("masscic");

    //Upload Handler to check image types
    function is_image($file) {

    $file_types = array('jpeg', 'gif', 'bmp'); //acceptable file types

    if ($img = getimagesize($file)){

        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($_FILES); //will return an array of information for testing
        //print_r($img); //will return an array of information for testing

        if(in_array(str_replace('image/', '', $img['mime']), $file_types))
        return $img;
    }
    return false;
}
    //form submission handling
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //file variables

    $fname = $_FILES['files']['name'];
    $ftype = $_FILES['files']['type'];
    $fsize = $_FILES['files']['size'];
    $tname = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
    $ferror = $_FILES['files']['error'];
    $newDir = '../uploads/'; //relative to where this script file resides

    for ($i = count($fname) -1; $i >=0; $i--) {
        if ($ferror[$i] =='UPLOAD ERR OK' || $ferror[$i] ==0) 

        {   

            if(is_image($tname[$i]))
            {
                move_uploaded_file($tname[$i], ($newDir.time().$fname[$i])); 
                echo '<li><span class="success">'.$fname[$i].' -- image has been accepted<br></span></li>';

            }else 
                echo '<li><span class="error">'.$fname[$i].' -- is not an accepted file type<br></span></li>';
        }
    }
}
            $sqlInsert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO files (file_names) VALUES('$fname')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

When uploading multiple files (with the same field name) another dimension is added to the array. Say I upload a.html and b.html, I'll get:

```
$_FILES['files']['name'][0]; // a.html
$_FILES['files']['name'][1]; // b.html
$_FILES['files']['size'][0]; // size of a.html
$_FILES['files']['size'][1]; // size of b.html
```

To iterate through:

```
for(var $i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++) {
    echo 'File name ' . $_FILES['files']['name'][$i] . ' has size ' . $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
}
```

This is explained at http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: Hi there. I've read that page extensively but I couldn't quite understand it. Which is why I thought of a "foreach" loop. Are you saying I should substitute my for loop for the one above? If so, your for loop gives a parse error.

Comment: I fixed the parse error and got this to insert into the database but it creates three separate records. That is if a user uploads three files, three separate records are created in the database. I would like to get all three files to be counted as one record into one database column named "files" in the database.